# How to calculate sides, twists and loops of mobius strip continuously cut in half?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Say I had a mobius strip and I cut it in half, then I did it again and again. Is there a formula to get the number of sides, twists and loops that make up the resulting strip based on the number of times the strip in halved?

Comment: Have you tried it?  The first two cuts are very instructive.  A strip with an odd number of half-twists has one side and one edge, a strip with an even number of half-twists has two sides and two edges.

Comment: I understand that much, but is there a mathematical correlation between the number of twists and the number of times you have cut the strip? I am pretty sure there is, I am wondering just what that is. I have tried the actual cutting, but I am having a difficult time managing all the paper and line drawing.

Comment: After one cut, what do you have? After two cuts, what do you have?  How many strips, and how many twists on each?  Once you make the second cut, the pattern is easy to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first cut gives you a single loop with a full twist, which has two sides and two edges.  After that each (set of) cut(s) doubles the number of loops.  Each loop still has two sides, two edges, and two half-twists.